# Is there any way to make the menu bar on macbook floating?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I saw on google an article that had that kind of showing the Menu Bar of a mac, and I was wondering if there is a way to implement it.
Thanks in advance!

The article is from 9to5mac : https://9to5mac.com/2021/08/09/concept-macos-mammoth-should-redefine-the-mac-experience-with-major-changes-to-the-desktop-menu-bar-widgets-search-and-the-dock/

[image]

Comment: Link to the article?

Comment: the link to the article: https://9to5mac.com/2021/08/09/concept-macos-mammoth-should-redefine-the-mac-experience-with-major-changes-to-the-desktop-menu-bar-widgets-search-and-the-dock/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Mammoth is just an artist saying what they think might be a better interface.

There is no actual implementation or any indication that Apple have even seen this let alone made any implementation.

There is no API in macOS to alter the menu bar in this way

Comment: thank you fam!sad that there is no implement to this

Comment: actually, bartender 5 have this feature. but it's kinda buggy at the moment. hoping they'll improve it because it looks cool.